# Cannot return a true value on a boolean

Tags: java, boolean

I'm working on my university homework and i have faced this problem. What i need to accomplish is when the user inputs a metallic element of either zinc, iron, aluminum and sodium i want the program to return true.  When the element which is compared is true, the boolean still outputs false. Can you please identify the problem in this code?

**class `IonicCompound`**

```
public class IonicCompound {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a metallic element: ");
        String element1 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter a non-metallic element: ");
        String element2 = input.nextLine();
        Elements element = new Elements(element1, element2);
        element.isMetal(element.first);
        if (element.isMetal(element.first) == true) {
            System.out.println("It's a metallic element ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It's not a metallic element ");
        }
    }
}
```

**class `Elements`**

```
public class Elements {

    public String first, second;

    public Elements(String f, String s) {
        first = f;
        second = s;
    }

    public boolean isMetal(String ff) {
        if (ff == "iron" || ff == "Iron" || ff == "aluminium" || ff == "Aluminium" || ff == "sodium" || ff == "Sodium" || ff == "zinc" || ff == "Zinc") {
            return isMetal(ff) == true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        String element = first + " " + second;
        return element;
    }
```

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==`. See: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839)

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `isMetal` from inside `isMetal`, so you're recursing indefinitely.  I think what you want is simply `return true;`

Also, take a look at function `String.equals`.  The `==` operator probably isn't doing what you expect in Java.

Answer (score 2):

To compare strings use the String API equals method. Below is an example that can be applied in your code:

```
ff.equals("iron") // This compares if String contain the same series of characters

ff=="iron" // this compares if the memory address of the ff variable is "iron"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Equals was the problem, now it works perfectly.

Comment: please use equalsIgnoreCase() to ensure it returns true for "iron" and "Iron".

Answer (score 1):

Use `.equals()` as opposed to `==` when comparing objects (Strings are objects). `==` will compare the objects' references, whereas `.equals()` will check to see if they have the same values. Since two objects will very rarely have the same reference you should never use `==` except for comparing primitive types (int, char, but String is not a primitive type!) where it doesn't matter.

So you want

```
ff.equals(iron)
```